# How to spawn objects at mouse cursor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to instantiate objects where my mouse is. I tried to do that (code below), but in my attempt the object is always being spawned at the center of the screen. What can I do to fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CraftingControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] selectedObjectArray = new GameObject[3];
    public GameObject selectedObject;
    // Use this for initialization


    void Update()
    {
        if (selectedObject == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))//Here im getting postion and spawning objects
        {
            Vector3 tempMousePost = Input.mousePosition;
            Vector3 mousePost = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(tempMousePost);
            mousePost.y = 0;
            Instantiate(selectedObject, mousePost, transform.rotation);

        } 

    }
    void OnGUI()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
        {
            GUI.Box(new Rect(100, 100, 300, 300), "Crafting");
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(125, 125, 100, 50), "Campfire"))
            {
                selectedObject = selectedObjectArray[0];
            }

            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(125, 200, 100, 50), "Tent"))
            {
                selectedObject = selectedObjectArray[1];
            }
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(125, 275, 100, 50), "Fence"))
            {
                selectedObject = selectedObjectArray[2];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you building a 2D or 3D game?

Comment: @pasotee placing an object from a 2d screen into a 3d world would be interesting wouldnt it, especially without us knowing how it should be placed.

Comment: You should not be using `OnGUI` (aka "Immediate Mode GUI")  for game development. It is intended for creating editor controls only You need to be using the new [UI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` returns a point in the world corresponding to where the **lens** of your camera is.  It doesn't return the world coordinate of the geometry under the mouse, which I suspect is what you want.  For that you will need to do a raycast into the scene and find where the intersection lies.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to raycast at the mouse position and set the Z value back if you are going for a 2D project:

```
 Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
 RayCastHit rayHit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out rayHit))
        {
           Vector3 position = rayHit.point;
           position.z = 0f;
           Instantiate(yourGameObject, position, Quaternion.Identity);
        }
```